# Any desktop application metric services (think Flurry for OS X)?

Tags: metrics

What are the options for desktop application metrics collection in 2013?

I know of Usermetrix and Deskmetrix, but surely they can't be the only ones? If you look at mobile analytics services the market seems to be a lot more developed.

Specifically I am looking for usage analysis (stuff like retention, crash reports, custom event reporting, version tracking.

EDIT: I should note that I'm aware of the similar questions but they're a few years old and was hoping to get an up to date picture, especially since the advent of the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [**Trackerbird Software Analytics**](http://www.trackerbird.com).

SDK is available for .NET/C++/Python and Mac OS X. Integration takes just a few minutes and apart from basic installation/usage tracking you can also use it for in-app marketing and conversion analysis.

Disclaimer: I am affiliated with the company.

Answer (score 1):

While [Deskmetrix](https://deskmetrics.com/) seems quite nice, I ended up using [Tapstream](http://tapstream.com) because it's free and Deskmetrix is pretty expensive.

Since Tapstream's main focus is evaluating advertisement campaigns its analytics feature is rather poor (compared to Flurry for instance). However, they allow custom event tracking.

When developing [Mils](https://milsapp.com), it was of great help that Tapstream supports both Mac OS X and Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I've been successfully using [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/) (which has a free tier): they don't have an official Mac SDK (iOS only) but I've written a simple Obj-C wrapper for their APIs: https://github.com/swisspol/MixpanelTracker